# HTML ¿Cómo quitar el name="value" al hacer un submit?

Tags: php, html, login

Buenas a todos.
Estoy tratando de hacer un login y con el problema que me encuentro es que al hacer click en el botón de iniciar sesión envía el string con el nombre del input y un "=".
Por ej: envía el email y password de la siguiente manera `"email=jorge@ejemplo.com&password=123"`.

Y en mi dirección php necesito que sólo reciba el valor escrito.
Ahora mi pregunta es, hay forma de que sólo se envíe el string escrito en el campo de texto sin el `name="value"`?

Les dejo el código hasta ahora. Gracias de antemano.

Login Test

```
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="http://milogin.com.ar/app_cliente31.php?pf=dame_tipo&p0=">

        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresar Email" required>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
          <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Ingresar Contraseña" required>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Mantener la sesión iniciada</label>
        </div>
        <button id="btnIniciarSesion" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Iniciar Sesión</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
</body>
```

justo despues del `?pf=dame_tipo&p0=` necesito que esté el email.

**EDIT:**
Lo pude solucionar de la siguiente manera.

```
<form action="/app_cliente31.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="pf" value="dame_tipo" /><!-- este de aquí es "hidden" -->
    <input type="email" id="email" name="p0" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresar Email" required />
</form>
```

Comment: Puedes agregar tu codigo js?

Comment: Si en el valor de `p0` necesitas que este el `email` entonces a tu `input` en el `html` le debes de colocar `name="p0"`, el `name` de un `input` es el nombre con el cual el valor se recibe en el `Back-End` por lo cual no se puede quitar en el método convencional (que veo que es el que estás usando)

Comment: @Gerardo No tengo código JS.

Comment: @CamiloVasquez no funciona cambiar el name por "p0".

Comment: Muéstrame como te queda la url después de dar click al submit

Comment: @CamiloVasquez con el `name=p0` queda así: `http://milogin.com.ar/app_cliente31.php?p0=jorge@ejemplo.com` 
y en el form action borré el `p0=`

Comment: Y no es eso lo que necesitas cuando dices "justo despues del ?pf=dame_tipo&p0= necesito que esté el email."

Comment: Sí, pero el `?pf=dame_tipo&p0=` desaparece y la página no carga :S

Comment: A que te refieres con "desaparece y la página no carga" ? Que comportamiento tiene ? sale algún mensaje?

Comment: Me refiero a que ya no aparece en la URL; literalmente. Para que la página cargue tiene que ser URL completo (milogin.com.ar/app_cliente31.php?pf=dame_tipo&p0=EMAIL"‌), si no, no funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que el `form` simplemente está mandando un `get`, las peticiones de este tipo mandan la información en la URL, que es lo que te está pasando. Como los recibes en el servidor es así:

```
$_GET["pf"];
$_GET["email"];
$_GET["password"]
```

Si quieres ocultar de la url estos datos, necesitas hacerlo mediante una petición `post`:

```
<form action="http://milogin.com.ar/app_cliente31.php?pf=dame_tipo&p0=" method="post">
```

De esta manera, puedes **(y deberías)** ocultar datos como correos y contraseñas. La manera de recibir los datos en el servidor es:

```
$_POST["email"];
$_POST["password"];
```

Puedes asegurarte de que se hayan enviado estos datos mediante la instrucción `isset`:

```
if(isset($_POST["email"])){
    ...
}
```

Para más detalles sobre esto puedes [consultar la guía de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.external.php) al respecto.

---

#### EDIT

De acuerdo a lo que comentas, lo que necesitas hacer es cambiar tu input de email así:

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="p0" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresar Email" required>
                                ^^^^^^^
```

Cambia el `name` del input po `p0` para que así te lo tome la dirección. Esto es porque los nombres de los datos que mandes son lo que pongas en la propiedad `name`.

---

#### EDIT 2

De acuerdo a lo que dices, hay que colocar un input con el campo que requieres de esta manera:

```
<form action="/app_cliente31.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="pf" value="dame_tipo" /><!-- este de aquí es "hidden" -->
    <input type="email" id="email" name="p0" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresar Email" required />
    ...
</form>
```

De esta manera el dato `pf` será enviado sin necesidad de mostrarlo en el formulario.

Comment: Sí, es justamente lo que necesito, mandar información a la URL, que debería quedar asi "http://milogin.com.ar/app_cliente31.php?pf=dame_tipo&p0=EMAIL". Con hacer eso ya solucionaría-

Comment: Actualicé de acuerdo a lo que comentaste, revisa si te sirve :D

Comment: Hice esto previamente y no tuve suerte. En vez de quedar como la url del comentario anterior, una parte se pierde quedando así (`http://milogin.com.ar/app_cliente31.php?p0=luis@email.com`). Podrá ser que caracteres como el "&"  y el "=" en el "form action" tienen que ver?

Comment: Es probable. Acabo de actualizar mi respuesta, ve si te sirve!

Comment: Justamente ayer, hice esto mismo y lo pude solucionar, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder Kroneaux.